# chart js doesn't return tooltip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I'm working with chart js and coule days ago QA found out a small bag in my app, on which I'm stuck. 
The problem is when data is empty or equal 0, tooltip of chart js shows nothing just an empty arrow

How can I fix it that it is show for me just 0 in this situation?

this is my screenshot:
[image]

this is my loop where I'm getting my data:

```
for (var idx in fullData.sections) {
                    var section = fullData.sections[idx];
                    for (var gaugeIdx in section.gauges) {
                        var gauge = section.gauges[gaugeIdx];
                        var topGauge = $scope.getGaugeData(gauge.id);
                        if (topGauge.chartData) {
                            topGauge.chartData[0].unshift(gauge.value);
                            topGauge.chartLabels.unshift(dd);
                        } else if (topGauge.chartData[0].unshift(gauge.value == 0)){
                            return topGauge.chartData[0].unshift(gauge.value == 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I've been tried to play with tooltipTemplate but everything was useless

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What is the value of your `tooltipTemplate` option? What happens if you just leave it with the default?

Comment: this is my value of tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>". It is default and I even deleted this line at all and nothing has been changed. That's why I guess this line doesn't impact on my chart

Comment: I bet that the `value` property is `undefined` or `null` or something. If you don't have a value and you don't have a `label` either, the tooltip will be empty. *edit* oh wait, sorry :) that's what you already said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is

```
text: template(this.options.tooltipTemplate, Element) ? template(this.options.tooltipTemplate, Element) : '0',
```

just fix this 1040 line in my ChartJs and now it's working.
Thanks Pointy for hint

Answer (score 0):

You could try this tooltip template:

```
tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value||'0' %>"
```

That forces an explicit `0` string to be used when the value is empty.

Comment: unfortunately it's still 0 but you gave me an idea how to fix it